# How to find the current position of a UIListBox programmatically in runtime in windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

My requirement is that, i have a list box whose length depends on the number of items present in that list. After the list is over i just want to add some text fields exactly below it. So how can i find the y_coordinate position of the list box, so that i can append my textbox programmatically, below thw list box correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding both control within stack by code,

```
        StackPanel stack;           
        stack = new StackPanel();
        stackFinal.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;
        stackFinal.Children.Add(listToAdd);
        stack.Children.Add(textboxToAdd);
```

Answer (score 1):

I also Tried lot of things and after that I find some thing like this, using with "**Long List Selector**", Adding "**More**" Button to the End of the List.

`

```
<phone:LongListSelector>                
   <phone:LongListSelector.ListFooterTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <Button Name="BtnMore" Click="BtnMore_Click" Content="More..." />
      </DataTemplate>
   </phone:LongListSelector.ListFooterTemplate>                    
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

`

Then you can add items to the list when Button Clicks.